# Padding overflows the container in a text field

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to assign a padding to a text field, but the right side overlays the main content. How can i fix it?

```
     <div class='contenedor_section'>
      <input type='text' placeholder='name' class='estilo_input_text'>
     </div>


    .contenedor_section{
      padding: 20px;
      background:red;
    }
    .estilo_input_text {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 34px;
        padding: 6px 12px;
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 1.42857143;
        color: #555;
        background-color: #fff;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-radius: 4px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
        -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
        transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    }

    ::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
      font-style: italic;
      color: #999999 !important;
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ys0yb15s/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Negate the padding you applied. Or use border-box.
calc function is very handy, and widely supported, use it!

```css
.contenedor_section{
  padding: 20px;
  background:red;
}
.estilo_input_text {
    display: block;
    width: calc(100% - 24px);/* you have to negate the padding of 12px on each side */
    height: 34px;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #555;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
    -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
  font-style: italic;
  color: #999999 !important;
}
```

```html
  <div class='contenedor_section'>
    <input type='text' placeholder='name' class='estilo_input_text'>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `box-sizing: border-box;` to `.estilo_input_text`. This includes padding and borders in the width/height settings.

https://jsfiddle.net/k9at43zg/

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution: add `width: calc(100% - 24px);` to your `.estilo_input_text`:

```
.estilo_input_text {
    width: calc(100% - 24px);

}
```

## link https://jsfiddle.net/dalinhuang/LLyhwr64/

```css
.contenedor_section{
  padding: 20px;
  background:red;
}
.estilo_input_text {
    display: block;
    width: calc(100% - 24px);
    height: 34px;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #555;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
    -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
  font-style: italic;
  color: #999999 !important;
}
```

```html
  <div class='contenedor_section'>
    <input type='text' placeholder='name' class='estilo_input_text'>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

box-sizing: border-box; /**Added this**/

```css
.contenedor_section{
  padding: 20px;
  background:red;
}
.estilo_input_text {
   box-sizing: border-box;/**Added this**/
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 34px;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #555;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
    -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
  font-style: italic;
  color: #999999 !important;
 
}
```

```html
<div class='contenedor_section'>
    <input type='text' placeholder='name' class='estilo_input_text'>
  </div>
```